# binding to Iterates through Object in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to iterate through data objects for hours now, can I get assistance.

this what I have done so far.

**details.component.html**

```
 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
     this.repos = this.APiService.getRepos(changes.keywords.currentValue)
     .subscribe((res) =>  console.log(res))
  console.log('target', this.repos)

  }
```

**details.component.html**

```
<div>
    <ul *ngFor="let repo of repos | keyvalue">
        <li>{{repo.name}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Console:

[image: console image]

Comment: Show the code what you've tried so far, but I can't understand the question. You can iterate through an array with a for or foreach loop.

Comment: @Natixcoi have edited my code

Comment: You're setting `this.repos` to the subscription.

Comment: @BrandonDyer yes, what do you suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the repos in your subscription.

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    this.APiService
        .getRepos(changes.keywords.currentValue)
        .subscribe(res => this.repos = res);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort @Brandon 

without the keyvalue i get the data  with this warning in the console

`object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.`